# how to get NSInteger Values from sqlite Data BAse in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

How to get integer values from iPhone SQLite data base normally we use following was for varchar or string but how can we get NSInteger values?

```
    const char *sql = "select * from questions";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            DataController *coffeeObj = [[DataController alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];

            coffeeObj.restaurantLocation = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

            coffeeObj.foodQualityRating = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
```

restaurantlocation and foodquality rating or NSString I have survey id in Integer how can we fetch that from table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the surveyId field is the next column in the table after food quality you would use the following code:

```
coffeeObj.surveyId = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 3);
```

The 3 at then end of the statement is the column index

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code to get integer value from SQlite database

```
NSInteger i=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this 
NSInteger i=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);